# how can we dynamically add field using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

in here below code i want to create when i click on add new button then only dropdown list is add and when we select the list option  then its showing input name field but in here what happen is when i click the add new button then its automatically name field is add thats should not happen actually .how can we do that. anyone help me out this.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        $("#dropdown").change(function() {
            $("#addNew").prop("disabled", false);
        });

        $("#addNew").click(function() {
            $("#dropdown").append($(new Option("New option", 4)));
        });
    })
    
    
    $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
    $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
        $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
    });
    $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
        if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
            $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
    });
});
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select").change(function(){
            $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
                var val = $(this).attr("value");
                if(val){
                    $(".msg").not("." + val).hide();
                    $("." + val).show();
                } else{
                    $(".msg").hide();
                }
            });
        }).change();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
 <div class="multi-fields">
 <div class="multi-field">
<select id="dropdown" >
    <option value="">Please Select...</option>
    <option value="yellow">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option 2 ">Option 2</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
 <div class="yellow msg" style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;">name<input type="text" style="
    margin-left: 75px;
"></div>
</div>
 </div>
<button type="button" class="add-field" id="addNew" disabled >Add new</button>
</div>
```

Comment: anyone help me out this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your `.msg` div when you cloned your select using `$(cloned).find('.msg').hide()` and then append that in your *DOM* . Also , i have made some changes inside your select event i.e : to hide only required `.msg` divs.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  $("#dropdown").change(function() {
    $("#addNew").prop("disabled", false);
  });

  $("#addNew").click(function() {
    $("#dropdown").append($(new Option("New option", 4)));
  });
})


$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
  var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
  $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
    var cloned = $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true)
    $(cloned).find('select').attr('id', 'dropdown' + ($(".multi-field").length)) //id should be unique so..
    $(cloned).find('input').val('');
    $(cloned).find('.msg').hide() //hide msg div
    $(cloned).appendTo($wrapper)
  });
  $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
    if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
      $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  //use like ths because other selets are created dynmically
  $(document).on("change", "select", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    //hide only div where select-box there
    $(this).closest('.multi-field').find(".msg").hide();
    if (val) {
      //show same
      $(this).closest('.multi-field').find("." + val).show();
    }
  })
  $("select").trigger('change')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
  <div class="multi-fields">
    <div class="multi-field">
      <select id="dropdown">
        <option value="">Please Select...</option>
        <option value="yellow">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option 2 ">Option 2</option>
      </select>
      <button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
      <div class="yellow msg" style="display: block;margin-left: 50px;">name<input type="text" style="
    margin-left: 75px;
"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="add-field" id="addNew" disabled>Add new</button>
</div>
```